How to write Rails scope for this SQL query
I have an issue to get rows from database by multiple conditions.
I have a table Slot and SlotAlteration.
The slot has a time_off_id field.
SlotAlteration has two columns, slot_id and action. Action can be 0 or 1. Each slot can have up to two entries in the SlotAlteration table with action 0 and 1 (not 0 and 0, and not 1 and 1) or have no connections to SlotAlteration at all.
Query i need to convert into rails scope is
select *
from Slot s
where time_off_id is null
and not exists (
  select 1 from Slot 
  left outer join SlotAlteration a 
  on s.id = a.slot_id 
  where a.action = 1
)
order by s.id;

Alterr is SlotAlteration table
This is sql structure and query for visual representation.
https://dbfiddle.uk/yejKnaAi
My Slot model has association
has_many :alterations
  scope :free, -> {
    left_joins(:alterations)
      .where(time_off_id: nil)
      .where.not(alterations: { action: 1 })
  }

I tried that, but this is not select slots that are haven't alterations

I would add a dedicated has_many association for alternations with action = 1. Which means the associations might look like this:
# in app/models/slot.rb
has_many :alternations, class_name: 'SlotAlternation'
has_many :action_1_alternations, -> { where(action: 1) }, class_name: 'SlotAlternation'

Then you should be able to query for records without such an associated record.
Slot
  .where(time_off_id: nil)
  .where.missing(:action_1_alternations)

Note that the missing query method was introduced in Ruby on Rails 6.1 and is not available in Rails versions prior 6.1.

Not exactly. The left join is on the association with a scope only allowing action = 1 records. That means if action_1_alternations associations are missing, then the left join is either id: nil or there were only action != 1 records. So the association represents the sub query and the missing the outer left join with not exist.

We can accomplish this using NOT IN() with a subquery like so:
scope :free, -> { 
  where(time_off_id: nil)
  .where.not(id:SlotAlteration.select(:slot_id).where(action: 1))
} 

This will result in
SELECT 
  slots.* 
FROM 
  slots 
WHERE 
  slots.time_off_id IS NULL AND 
  slots.id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT 
      slot_alterations.slot_id 
    FROM 
      slot_alterations 
    WHERE 
      slot_alterations.action = 1
  )

If you really want to use EXISTS then you could also go with the following:
scope :free, -> { 
  where(time_off_id: nil)
  .where.not(
    SlotAlteration.select(1)
     .where(action: 1)
     .where(SlotAlteration.arel_table[:slot_id].eq(Slot.arel_table[:id))
     .arel.exists)
}

This will produce:
SELECT 
  slots.* 
FROM 
  slots 
WHERE 
  slots.time_off_id IS NULL AND 
  NOT ( EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 
      1
    FROM 
      slot_alterations 
    WHERE 
      slot_alterations.action = 1 AND slot_alterations.slot_id = slots.id
  ))


Unfortunately Rails don't support EXISTS condition although it is often more effective query method than JOIN
You can read about Rails core opinion in this issue
But you can use external gems, for example where_exists
# This taken from @spickermann answer
# app/models/slot.rb
has_many :alternations, class_name: 'SlotAlternation'
has_many :action_1_alternations, -> { where(action: 1) }, class_name: 'SlotAlternation'

And after that:
Slot
  .where(time_off_id: nil)
  .where_not_exists(:action_1_alternations)


After that, you can using .missing instead additional gem.
 .where.missing(:action_1_alternations)
But answer is fully closed my issue!

@RomanMin missing uses JOIN. EXISTS works faster, especially when you have large tables

You can do EXISTS in Rails. There just are no methods for it in the query interface and producing it with Arel is somewhat awkward.

it will be easy to debug if you share the corresponding SQL query generated on the scope which you have written.
if the Not NUll values to be included, you can also verify this by selecting the not null values in the query along with !=1.
That might Helps for you .
use where clause instead of where ! and include null as weell.
scope :free, -> {
  left_joins(:alterations)
    .where(time_off_id: nil)
    .where("alterations.id IS NULL OR alterations.action != ?", 1)
}


It selects me slots that have alteration.action = 0 even if they have alteration.action = 1, but it shouldn't include that rows
